# Need help connecting to MongoDB cluster on Android

Tags: c#, android, mongodb, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a mobile app with Xamarin Forms and intend to use a Mongo database.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with the **MongoDB Driver Version 2.9.2** and **android 28** as target SDK version.

I created a cluster on MongoDB Atlas, whitelisted all IP addresses for now, and tried to connect the app to the cluster with the connection string I was provided for the cluster(in the code below I replaced the real username and password with placeholders).

Here's the code:

```
private const string CONNECTION_STRING = "mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-uswax.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

var client = new MongoClient(CONNECTION_STRING);
```

If I run the program with the Android emulator, the line where the MongoClient is created is where the program crashes with the following exception:

```
System.AggregateException
  Message=Error resolving name servers (Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source) (Could not find file "/etc/resolv.conf")
  Source=DnsClient
  StackTrace:
  at DnsClient.NameServer.ResolveNameServers (System.Boolean skipIPv6SiteLocal, System.Boolean fallbackToGooglePublicDns) [0x0005e] in <93b57b4b99c64a96a2c065ea9ae1fc1f>:0 
  at DnsClient.LookupClient..ctor () [0x00000] in <93b57b4b99c64a96a2c065ea9ae1fc1f>:0 
  at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ConnectionString.Resolve (System.Boolean resolveHosts) [0x00011] in <bfbe70fcd6734952960e694cb03fd3c6>:0 
  at MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrl.Resolve (System.Boolean resolveHosts) [0x00015] in <f2c302ca191a4adf889da299a582e348>:0 
  at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClientSettings.FromUrl (MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrl url) [0x0001b] in <f2c302ca191a4adf889da299a582e348>:0 
  at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString (System.String connectionString) [0x00006] in <f2c302ca191a4adf889da299a582e348>:0 
  at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient..ctor (System.String connectionString) [0x00000] in <f2c302ca191a4adf889da299a582e348>:0 
  at Socializer.Helpers.MongoCrud..ctor (System.String connectionString, System.String databaseName) [0x00008] in D:\Data\projects\xamarin\Socializer\Socializer\Socializer\Helpers\MongoCrud.cs:18 
  at Socializer.App..ctor () [0x0001b] in D:\Data\projects\xamarin\Socializer\Socializer\Socializer\App.xaml.cs:27 
  at Socializer.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x0002f] in D:\Data\projects\xamarin\Socializer\Socializer\Socializer.Android\MainActivity.cs:24 
  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in <11a340ccc8de43f09c97400139266ef5>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.8(intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

When I was looking for a solution to this problem I found this [bug report](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2575),
stating that "*Android is not currently a supported platform for the .NET driver*"

Does that mean I cannot use MongoDB for Android applications or is there any other way? Thanks!

**Edit:** I also found [this possible solution](https://www.oipapio.com/question-17391559). The user that provided the answer states that "*from Android 8 (Oreo), access to net.dns has been removed*". Indeed when I remove `android:targetSdkVersion="28"` from my AndroidManifest.xml, the program no longer crashes, but that won't be an option once I want to upload the app to the play store. 
The solution above is based on a custom implementation to get DNS servers but I do not know how I would implement this function into my code. I would appreciate it a lot if anyone could help me with that.

Here is the function:

```
public List<IPEndPoint> GetDnsServers()
        {
            var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
            List<IPEndPoint> endPoints = new List<IPEndPoint>();
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
        (ConnectivityManager)context.GetSystemService(MainActivity.ConnectivityService);

            Network activeConnection = connectivityManager.ActiveNetwork;
            var linkProperties = connectivityManager.GetLinkProperties(activeConnection);

            foreach (InetAddress currentAddress in linkProperties.DnsServers)
            {
                IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(currentAddress.HostAddress), 53);
                endPoints.Add(endPoint);
            }
            return endPoints;
        }
```

Comment: about using MongoDB in Xamarin.forms, I find one article about this:https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/write-apps-using-mongodb-xamarin/

Comment: I was getting that same error and I solve it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58750964/getting-system-aggregate-exception-when-trying-to-connect-to-mongodb-client-in-x/59678026#59678026

Comment: I ever got DnsClient.DnsResponseException, solved it by changing DNS of my phone to use '8.8.8.8'. Worth a try

Answer (score 3):

I got this issue too. It turns out that, MongoDB Driver on Xamarin Android doesn't support ***DNS Seedlist Connection Format*** (starts from "`mongodb+srv://`") very well. So you have to use ***Standard Connection String Format*** (starts from "`mongodb://`").

Please go to Atlas and find your Standard Connection String by selecting an old version driver like C#/.NET 2.4

For more discription of these two connection ways, refer to [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)