# Getting System Aggregate Exception when trying to connect to MongoDB client in Xamarin

Tags: c#, mongodb, xamarin

I have a MongoDB database on a remote Azure server.
I have an app I'm writing on Xamarin and I'm trying to connect to my remote server, but I always get an exception as following:

**System.AggregateException: 'Error resolving name servers (Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source) (Could not find file "/etc/resolv.conf")'**

I'm getting this exception from this line of code:

```
var client = new MongoClient("connection_string");
```

The connection_string is the connection string I get from my Azure account, and I also tried connect to it from the Mongo Compass and it worked, so I'm guessing there's no problem of authentication or with the connection string.
Of course I also have the MongoDB nugets needed for connection to this database.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: are you directly accessing remote mongo db from the app? 

Comment: How else should I do it? I followed the exact instructions from this official guide:
https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/#connect-to-mongodb-atlas

Comment: Create an Api and hide your mongo db behind it. Otherwise your database is exposed to the world. What's more manipulating with database directly is not a good practice. Take a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I think that I get what your'e saying, I do have a protected class dealing with the DB connections and I use its method throughout the app where needed. 
Nevertheless, correct me if I'm wrong, this line of code should work and the exception I get doesn't make sense...

Comment: I ever got DnsClient.DnsResponseException, solved it by changing DNS of my phone to use '8.8.8.8'. Worth a try

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I was getting that exact same error, and after following several tutorial in internet without success, I managed to fix my problem by **installing via Nudget an earlier version of MongoDB: 2.7.0** instead of the last (2.10.0).