# Last version of MongoDB.Driver not working for Android 8+: Could not find file “/etc/resolv.conf”

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, mongodb.driver

I use last MongoDB.Driver v2.12.4 in my Xamarin VS project for Android 10. When i try to read data from server i get Exeption: Error resolving name servers (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.) (Could not find file “/etc/resolv.conf”) —> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. MongoDB.Driver used DNSClient and it cannot get dns servers correct in android 8+.

> Discussion of this problem is here **[Need help connecting to MongoDB cluster on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58674311/need-help-connecting-to-mongodb-cluster-on-android)**, but it solution working only for driver version 2.7.0. How can i configure last version MongoDB.Driver connection correct?

Comment: Don't connect directly to a database in your App but put it behind a Web Service. This way you can better handle security and scaling.

Comment: Can you show some example? And how Web Service fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

There was the same problem. Rolled back Mongo.Driver up to version 2.4.4., changed the connection string as written in the Atlas, and everything works.

Comment: Да оно работает и на версии 2.7.0, а почему на последней версии не работает? При использовании стандартной строки все равно ищет dns.